# Question deleted with upvoted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

[When can't I delete my own post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) says:

> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - ...
> - has an accepted answer, or

I received at least +30 for [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346499/bash-put-text-into-a-variable-without-needing-to-escape-characters/346504#346504), and then today [I'm told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) that the question (which had two upvotes) has been deleted by the OP. I'm also told that my reputation has disappeared along with it.

How was the delete possible given the quote above?

Given the quote is from a 241-upvote answer to a 304-upvote question, could a mod edit it if the quote is incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it was not deleted by OP. It was deleted by a moderator or high rep users for reasons of moderation:

> [image]

This is usually the case when questions are off topic for the site where they were posted.